# How to use binary decision variables in Geometric Programming?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, geometric-programming

I have formulated a MINLP and want to convert into Geometric Programming. There, I want to use binary decision variables. Can someone please guide me that how to declare and use binary decision variables in GP? I am using a $\textbf{ggplab}$ toolbox for Geometric Programming in Matlab.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use CVX in gp mode http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/gp.html . You can declare whatever variables you want as binary. If your program uses gp mode nad you have installed CVXQUAD, you will get a faster and more reliable solution process http://ask.cvxr.com/t/cvxquad-how-to-use-cvxquads-pade-approximant-instead-of-cvxs-unreliable-successive-approximation-for-gp-mode-log-exp-entr-rel-entr-kl-div-log-det-det-rootn-exponential-cone-cvxquads-quantum-matrix-entropy-matrix-log-related-functions/5598

Another maybe less easy to use but more reliable approach would be to use YALMIP https://yalmip.github.io/tutorial/geometricprogramming/ (declare binary variables using binvar), combined with the MOSEK 9 solver, which will allow Mosek 9's native mixed integer exponential cone solver capability to be employed.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Mr Mark, does geometric programming allow binary. I thought it require strict positive decision variables

Comment: Yes, mixed-integer geometric programming is possible in CVX, YALMIP, CVXPY, CVXR,  and Convex.jl .  Mosek can be used as solver.